# Force Chrome to download text from JavaScript plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have the following method which makes a download:

```
function DownloadTxtFile(filename, text) {
    var encodedData = encodeURIComponent(text);
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodedData);
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

The only problem is that *it doesn't work*! I have inspected both filename and text parameters via `console.log()`. They are definitely fine! It seems that for whatever reason `'a'` element doesn't get appended to the body. Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you doing it in the background page? Although it works for me even there.

Comment: How big is your text? It may be too long to stuff in a URI.

Comment: @Xan The lenght of text is depends upond situation. Up to now it was less than 20 lines. Max 1000 characters I believe. Pretty small!

Comment: Can you test it with something (really) short to exclude the length problem? Because your code works perfectly for me for short payloads.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].